# Looking for audio/speech filtering expert for mobile hearing app

Tags: speech-processing, audio-processing

I am an Ear-Nose-Throat doctor (hearing doctor), looking for some help from someone who has built a mobile app with Frequency Filtering and Amplification. I am working on a social impact program for a non-profit (part of WHO initiative, for World Deafness Eradication). I am trying to build a simple audio frequency filtering app on Mobile (at least Android, if not for both platforms), to help poor people who are hard of hearing in some frequencies and cannot afford to buy a hearing aid device. The basic idea is to boost the gain in some specific frequency bands. Can someone point me to some existing reference code that i can get some students to work on?

PS: This is a voluntary, self-funded project but I can try to get some good-faith donations for anyone offering time.

Comment: I suggest trying to contact researchers from this institute: https://www.rit.edu/ntid/research-overview

Comment: You may want to consider splitting this into two skill sets: A) someone who knows how to build and deploy mobile apps on your target platforms and target regions/languages. B) someone who can help with the actual audio design and filtering. I can help with the second. Feel free to pop me an e-mail at boston DOT bass DOT spam AT gmail dot com

Comment: Your endeavour may be limited by the available amplification of the devices you are targeting. Typical hearing aids allow for very high amplification of the critical frequencies, whereas a typical mobile phone will limit the output power to avoid hearing damage. Your signal processing (which, btw, should also include dynamic range processing) will be limited by the digital ceiling, so that amplifying the signal just by digital processing will probably not suffice. That said, you may be able to add a cheap amplification device between the user's earpieces and the mobile device.